# How many HH pairs appear in a 100-coin toss sequence?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, puzzle

What is the expected number of 2-consecutive-head pairs in a sequence of 100 fair coin flips, allowing overlap (HHH equals two pairs)?

Comment: Just use linearity.  Each of the first $99$ slots has a $\frac 14$ chance of being the start of an $HH$ pair.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the independent random variables $X_1,X_2,\dots, X_N$, where $N=100$ for short, taking the values $0,1$ with equal probability. We consider here an H to be one, a T to be zero. Then we need the mean (or expectation, expected value $\Bbb E$) of the variable $X_1X_2+X_2X_3+\dots+X_{N-1}X_N$, which is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\Bbb E[\ X_1X_2+X_2X_3+\dots+X_{N-1}X_N\ ]\\
&\qquad =\Bbb E[X_1X_2] + \Bbb E[X_2X_3]+\dots+\Bbb E[X_{N-1}X_N ]\\
&\qquad =\Bbb E[X_1]\;\Bbb E[X_2] + \Bbb E[X_2]\; \Bbb E[X_3]+\dots+\Bbb E[X_{N-1}]\; \Bbb E[X_N ]\\
&\qquad =\underbrace{\frac 12\cdot\frac 12 + \frac 12\cdot\frac 12+\dots+\frac 12\cdot\frac 12
}_{(N-1)\text{ times}}\\
&\qquad =\frac 14(N-1)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: This is the comment of @lulu from the OP, "linearity" allows a complete "disaggregation of matter", so that understanding all steps (with counting dependencies) together reduces to understanding one step (with split dependencies)...

Comment: how would one compute the variance of this?

Comment: The expectation of $(X_1X_2+\dots+X_{N-1}X_N)^2$ can be computed. After squaring, we need "only" to compute $\Bbb E[X_iX_{i+1}\; X_jX_{j+1}]$, $i\le j$, where and split into cases. (a) $i=j$, (b) $i+1=j$, and the remained case of four distinct indices.

Answer (score 0):

Quick estimate. Think of the sequence as wrapping around (makes the calculation easier). Then there are $100$ pairs. Each has a $25\%$ chance of being HH. So you expect $25$ such pairs.

Another way to look at it: each of the expected $50$ heads is equally likely to be followed by a head or a tail.

Comment: The exact value for the non-circle is $99/4.$ This is because there are 99 pairs, and, although the probabilities are dependent, expectations are still additive, and the expected number of times a pair happens at position $i$ is 1/4.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I keep forgetting how the additivity of expectation makes many problems like this easy.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y_i=1$  if $X_i=X_{i+1}=H$ , $Y_i=0$ elsewhere. We have $E[Y_i]=P(Y_i=1)=\frac14$.

Further, the number of HH pairs is  $T=\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} Y_i$ and

$$E[T]=  \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} E[Y_i]=(N-1) \frac14$$